Unexpected behaviour rewriting path to parameter using upon trailing slash htaccess mod_rewrite request_filename
I came across an unexpected behaviour rewriting the first (and second) folders of a nice-URL into parameter to be handled by PHP. As example "https://server.net/test2/" in the browser address bar to be rewritten internally to "/index.php?action=$1&content=$2" where $1 (and $2) are the folder names.
In order to avoid any endless loop and still be able to access existing files some conditional checks should be applied:

not already index.php (in main directory) is called
not an existing file is called directly (don't care about directories unless a specific file in the dir is called, see above)
rewrite to pass on first (and optional second) directory as params to index.php

From some research and testing with htaccess testers I came up with the following lines:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/?]+)(?:/([^/?]+))? /index.php?action=$1&content=$2 [L,QSA]

This works very well in most cases, but I encountered two odd behaviours I can't figure out what exactly happens why - and also the htaccess testers didn't give me a hint :-(

Opening "https://server.net/test?k" (where "test" is an existing folder) correctly does the rewrite, but this is visibile in the browser address bar, resulting there in "https://server.net/test/?action=test&content=&k" - Any chance to prevent this? My understanding was, that the rewrite happens only internally on the server...

Opening "https://server.net/test2/" (where "test2" is a name that exists as a file) triggers 404, obviously before the rewrite happens. Why? How can I prevent this?


Would be great, if somebody can point me into the right direction for a solution!? Thanks in advance!

Problem #1 would be mod_dir interfering; since you requested the directory without a trailing slash, it will perform a redirect to the version with the slash, mixed with the already internally rewritten URL parameters. If you don't want this, you'll have to set DirectorySlash to off- but heed the security warning.

And for #2 - requesting a file with a trailing slash would work, if AcceptPathInfo was enabled.

Hi @C3roe and thanks for your quick replies!
I tried adding DirectorySlash Off in the htaccess, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on #1 - it still seems to redirect to the rewrite URL "externally"...

Okay, found the solution for #1 - in addition to @C3roe answer, ie adding  DirectorySlash Off and to address the security warning mentioned also adding Options -Indexes the previous test calls in my browser got cached (hard) by mod_dir adding the trailing slash with a 301 redirect :-)

Your solution to #2 works perfectly, thanks :-)
